# react native fs don't read imported files

Tags: react-native, android-permissions, react-native-fs

I'm using react native fs to export and import data in json format from a sqllite db.
I'm writing and reading file MonthsData.json into DownloadDirectoryPath.

As long as I read and write the data through my app everything works fine.

If I download and upload the backup file from my pc with this commands

```
adb pull /storage/emulated/0/Download/MonthsData.json .
adb push .\MonthsData.json /storage/emulated/0/Download/
```

when I try to access the file

```
if (await getPermissions()) {
  let result = await RNFS.readFile(
    RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath + '/' + filename,
    'utf8',
  );

async function getPermissions(): Promise<boolean> {
  let isPermitedExternalStorage = await PermissionsAndroid.check(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
  );

  if (!isPermitedExternalStorage) {
    // Ask for permission
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      {
        title: 'Storage permission needed',
        message: 'Can read ?',
        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      },
    );
    return granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;
  }

  return true;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: /storage/emulated/0/Download/MonthsData.json: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied), open '/storage/emulated/0/Download/MonthsData.json'
```

If I try to list the file with the command

```
ls -la /storage/emulated/0/Download/
```

The owner and permissions are always the same both before and after the data upload

```
generic_x86_arm:/ $ ls -la /storage/emulated/0/Download/
total 12
-rw------- 1 u0_a149 u0_a149 6325 2022-02-20 14:34 MonthsData.json
```

I would appreciate every help or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the [AndroidPermissions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid) api to request the permission before attempting to read. The permissions in the android manifest are only automatically granted on older Android version

Comment: To avoid complicating the code I avoided inserting it here, but I ask for the Android Permissions in the getPermissions method

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround.
I create the file through my application.

Push the file with a different name

```
adb push .\MonthsData.json /storage/emulated/0/Download/MonthsDataTemp.json
```

Then I connect to my android terminal

```
adb shell

generic_x86_arm:/ $ cd  /storage/emulated/0/Download/
generic_x86_arm:/storage/emulated/0/Download $ cat MonthsDataTemp.json > MonthsData.json
```

Answer (score 0):

const path = `${ExternalStorageDirectoryPath}/Download`;

const options = {
fromUrl: url,
toFile: `${path}/${fileName}`,
};

downloadFile(options)
.promise.then(resp => {
...
} else {
...
}
})
.catch(err => {
....
});